# How to get a UIViewController that added a subview from subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView which is added to UIViewController.

UIView is a separate class and separate .h and .m files.

I want to present another UIViewController or something. How to access the UIViewController that added this UIView from UIView ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **No, you can't know which exactly is the view's view controller, because that would break MVC principles.**

---

I don't think you understood what [`MVC`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) means and stands for. It wouldn't be a good approach to present a view controller from a view object of another view controller. It is the view controller who should provide any information view needs from the outside world.

`UIView` objects are meant to just display UI components to screen and are responsible for drawing and laying out their child views correctly.

As I said above, you should handle those kind of interactions between the views  *(or communication channels, whatever you call it)* always in controllers to where they actually belong. In this context, you should present any view controller from another **view controller**, not another **view**. If you need to send messages from a view to its view controller, you can make use of the [delegate approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) or [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/) class.

If it were up to me, I would personally prefer using delegate when view needs some information from its view controller. It is more understandable than using notification center as it makes it much easier to keep track of information flow. However in your case, in other words  where view controller needs information from view (reverse communication), I'd go with the notification center.

So let's enrich this conversation with an example:

```
@implementation SomeView

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"value": [self someCalculatedValue]};

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ViewButtonClickedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}
@end
```

Note that, you should never leave the `object:` argument of `[NSNotificationCenter:postNotificationName:object]` method as `nil` since it will help the controller distinguish the notification sent by its view from other notifications.

```
@implementation SomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewButtonClicked:) name:ViewButtonClickedNotification object:self.view];
}

- (void)viewButtonClicked:(NSNotification *)
{
    NSNumber *someCalculatedValue = notification.userInfo[@"value"];

    [self presentViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] initWithCalculatedValue:someCalculatedValue] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

---

For more information about communication patterns in iOS, you might want to take a look at this great [article](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/communication-patterns.html) in order to comprehend how they work.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about previous comment.